# To count distinct file name in a directory using Shell scripting

Tags: shell

I have one Folder which consist of around 400 plus Files what i have to do to count number of distinct files as there may be more than one version of file.
Like For Eg If in a folder i have 8 files:-

V07Y_0021_YP_0100_001.PDF - This is unique

V07Y_0021_YP_0099_001.PDF - This is unique

V07Y_0021_YP_0003_001.PDF - This is duplicate _001.PDF is first version

V07Y_0021_YP_0003_002.PDF - This is duplicate _002.PDF is second Version

V07Y_0021_YP_0109_001.PDF - This is duplicate _002.PDF is first Version

V07Y_0021_YP_0108_001.PDF - This is unique

V07Y_0021_YP_0109_002.PDF - This is duplicate _002.PDF is second Version

In Above Files _0109,_0100,_0099 is Page Number and after these numbers _001,_002 is version.Also there can be more than two versions also of same file (Page No)
SO i have to implement a logic which will give me count as 5 as 2 files are duplicate so it will be counted only once.

I have tried various ways like find directoryName -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort -u
This dosent Worked for me as i have to find a pattern too.

If Anybody knows the ogic Please share.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should the output be? `find directoryName -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort -u` Good! now add a `sed` in between to filter only the interested part.

Comment: Can ou count the first version files `*_001.PDF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n' |
# Remove the version part
sed 's!_[0-9][0-9][0-9].PDF$!!' |
# remove duplicates
sort -u
```

would output:

```
V07Y_0021_YP_0003
V07Y_0021_YP_0099
V07Y_0021_YP_0100
V07Y_0021_YP_0108
V07Y_0021_YP_0109
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SpatialShinyCertifications#main.sh)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count :

```
ls targetDirectory/V07Y_0021_YP* | cut -d'_' -f4 | sort -u | wc -l
```

This would send you the number of unique items.
ls : list the files, cut : get the fourth item with '_' separator, sort : remove duplicates, wc : count lines

You can remove `| wc -l` to get the list of files.